# How do I push elements into a nested array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Here's what my JSON looks like

```
{
    "groups": [{
        "label": "Data Plane",
        "groups": [{
            "label": "Compliance Data %",
            "groups": [{
                "label": "Data1"
            }, {
                "label": "Data2"
            }, {
                "label": "Data3"
            }, {
                "label": "Data4"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I have parsed this JSON in my JS, and, I have managed to push the `Data Plane` into a new array. I would also like to push the labels `Compliance Data %` and the labels `Data1`, `Data2`, and `Data3` into the same array in the same **tree format** as that of the JSON.

I tried the `groups[0].groups[0].groups[0].push` function to push **to** the inner most label. But that doesn't work. I have already extracted the JSON object `label` and fed it to another array, and I'm trying to push these values. I would like to know how to push it to a new array **IN** the same structure.

Comment: Your push should work...what variable is this stored in?

Comment: I deleted my answer, as it is unclear to me what Planes exactly is, please name your variables in your example so that we can work it out.

Comment: Lol. Your answer actually worked. Turns out that in the new array, "Groups" actually wasn't defined. So, I just gave an empty "group" element, and it worked.

Comment: I undeleted my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't work because you are trying to push into an object literal, try this instead

```
var o = {
    "groups": [{
        "label": "Data Plane",
        "groups": [{
            "label": "Compliance Data %",
            "groups": [{
                "label": "Data1"
            }, {
                "label": "Data2"
            }, {
                "label": "Data3"
            }, {
                "label": "Data4"
            }]
        }]
    }]
};

o.groups[0].groups[0].groups.push({ label: "Data5" });
```

Comment: groups[0].groups[0].groups.push({label: json.groups[0].groups[0].groups[0].label}) says that "groups[0].groups[0].groups is undefined". As in the JSON is correct, the function is incorrect.

Comment: What I meant is to access from your object, I'll update my answer to clarify

Comment: Let me further clarify. I had made a new array called as "Planes". I was pushing to the "Data Plane" label via Planes.push({label : $LABEL_AQUIRED_FROM_JSON$}). I tried your method now. Planes.groups[0].groups[0].groups.push({label: "Data5"}] I still get Planes.groups is undefined.

Comment: Oh Planes.groups[0].groups.push then